# Remove unused JS with nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

Were using nuxt and the chrome coverage report shows a lot unused JS.

Is there a way to only JS necessary for a certain route?

[image]

Comment: It's unfortunately code that could be used, so it has to be bundled.  This is one of the problems with running a framework: lots of code that has to be added in case it is needed.  The best solution to this is to ditch the framework for pages you want great lighthouse scores on IMO

Comment: Nuxt states to only load JS Files that are being used for the current route. If you switch routes, other js is loaded with ajax. A frontend-framework should be able to know which js it needs to properly work and which not.

Comment: That's only true for loading your own code, or loading 3rd party libraries.  For example, rather than adding a library to your global plugins, only add it the a particular page.  However, Nuxt and Vue don't know what code they'll need on the browser.  There's shims, error handling, routing, and all kinds of other internal code  that isn't "needed" until it's needed.  You'll find the majority of your unused code is going to be due to this, especially if you're already careful about globally loading your own JS.

Comment: A great example of how misleading Lighthouse and Google are about "unused" code can be found in your screenshot: Google tag manager only uses 21% of its code according to that report.  That's simply due to the code not being called yet, but presumably it will be called in the future.

Comment: Regardless being used or not, the problem is performance affect the ranking in SEO

Answer (score 4):

I can help with 3 easy tips:

1. Make sure you are not loading a lot of plugins because plugins are loaded as global. Only use a plugin if this plugin is needed in all pages.
2. Check if you are importing (static) components in your layout that you are not really using becasuse you have a `v-if` sentence for example. Try to import components dynamically when you do not need them in your first content loaded.
3. For third party scripts, libs try to check if you can use tree shake and import only the features you need.

There are a lot of improvements you can apply to your website to reduce unused js but you can start checking these.

For CSS you can use Purge CSS (https://purgecss.com/)

Answer (score -1):

As I know not only these are not unused js but also when you use nuxt, it builds js for each part of your project and calls them depending on needs!

If you change the route you can see new js which calls to load new route.

You can see this short video to understand how nuxt works!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6airiY8e84

Comment: Yeah, and when it loads js dependent on what route you are, it should not load unnecessary js?

Comment: yes of course ! and  in comparison to other front-end technology (react.js and angular ) it is so optimize and high performance !

read this article can help you : 

https://blog.logrocket.com/angular-vs-react-vs-vue-a-performance-comparison/